# Scala case class whose fields can be mandatory and optional at different instances

Tags: scala, case-class, json4s

I've created two rest end-points in akka http which takes string as input, parse it using Json4s and then do processing on it. My case class is like -

```
final case class A(id: String, name: String, address: String)
```

1st end point receives only id while the other receives all three fields and I want to use the same case class A for both. So I used default values for name & address fields like -

```
final case class A(id: Stirng, name: String = "", address: String = "")
```

This is working good for me. But now if I don't send address or name (or both) fields at second end point, it does not throw an exception stating that the name (or address) not found.

So, my question is can I create one end point in which id is mandatory while other fields does not matter and another end point where every field is mandatory using same case class ? 
The code to parse the string to a case class is -

```
parse(jsonStr).extract[A]
```

I hope you're getting my point.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can't make a single endpoint with two different request. you will have to put validations.
use Option[String] for name and address. and when you are sending the name and address do name.get and address.get

Comment: with play-json you could use `Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues]` - maybe there is a similar concept with `json4s`

Comment: Use jsoniter-scala instead - it has the built-in handling of case class fields with default values as optional and also has an integration with akka-http: https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/pull/205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve what you want to do.

### Option + Validations

name and address are optional so you need to handle them.

```
case class A(id: String, name: Option[String], address: Option[String])

val json = """{ "id":"1" }"""

// 1st endpoint
val r = parse(json).extract[A]
r.name.getOrElse("foo")
r.address.getOrElse("bar")

// 2nd endpoint
val r2 = parse(json).extract[A]
r2.name.getOrElse(/* boom! */)
```

### Default JObject + Merge

or you can use an alternative JObject to provide default values to your input.

```
case class A(id: String, name: String, address: String)

val json = """{ "id":"1"  }"""

val defaultValues = JObject(("name", JString("foo")), ("address", JString("bar")))

// 1st endpoint
val r = defaultValues.merge(parse(json)).extract[A]

// 2nd endpoint
val r2 = parse(json).extract[A] // boom! again
```

Answer (score 1):

No your case class formally defines what you expect in input. It doesn't represent ambiguity. You could use optional and add checks. But that just defeats the purpose of extractor.